# Jetpack Compose - Unresolved reference: observeAsState

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose and I was trying to make a View Model for my @Composable.

In documentation (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#3) for observing state changes in composable they use `observeAsState` but in my implementation, the method cannot be found. I get instead `Unresolved reference: observeAsState`

ViewModel

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val list: LiveData<MutableList<String>> = MutableLiveData(mutableListOf("Ana", "are", "mere"))

    fun addString(item: String) {
        val list: MutableList<String> = list.value!!
        list.add(item)
    }

}
```

Composable
[image]

I am using Compose 1.0.0-beta01

Comment: Just FYI if anyone reads this and doesn't follow: the original question from 2021 refers to the State Codelab v2021. In 2022 a new State Codelab was created and uploaded, so the url above doesn't take you to a place where you can see the code and this API anymore, but a page in the new codelab. Cheers!

Answer (score 181, accepted):

`observeAsState` is part of the `runtime-livedata` library.

Add the dependency to your module's `build.gradle` file. Replace `$compose_version` with the version of compose which you use, e.g. `1.0.0-beta01`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
```

You can find the available versions [here in Google's Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.runtime/runtime-livedata).

Comment: Still, the same documentation is not updated for required dependencies

Comment: Is it part of `Compose`?

Answer (score 11):

Not exactly answering your question, but as a suggestion you could migrate to Flow instead of using live data.

ViewModel ->

```
val yourList: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf("String1","String2","String3"))
```

Composable ->

```
val yourList by yourViewModel.yourList.collectAsState()
```

Comment: The same.. The method is not found

Comment: did you properly imported the setters and getters?

Comment: the issue was with different libraries and versions

Comment: my question is which is convient way to use state like above observestate with live data ot collectAsstate with flow, I'm confused to which one use

Answer (score 3):

`CollectAsStateWithLifecycle` is now recommended for Android by google devs and it's lifecycle api is also stable.Flow is also recommended by devs.