# Jetpack compose lifecycle viewmodel: -> unresolved reference: compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I copied over the code from this website to play/pause an audio with a single button which changes icons:
https://semicolonspace.com/android-compose-music-button/

First I got this error:
[Jetpack Compose - Unresolved reference: observeAsState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560404/jetpack-compose-unresolved-reference-observeasstate)
but the first anser of the question resolved it.

Now however, on the following line:

```
androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()
```

I still get this error:
MainActivity.kt: Unresolved reference: compose
[code-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkyIa.png)

There is nothing I can import anymore and I have copied over the code as is on the website.

I refreshed my build.gradle too, such that it takes effect, but didnt help

**EDIT:**

Here is a github repo in case you would like to inspect this small project yourself, it's just the MainActitiy file, only a few lines of code like on the link above:
https://github.com/folsze/unresolved-reference-compose

Comment: You need special dependency in `build.gradle`: `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1'`.

Comment: Note please, that instead of manually hard code versions in `build.gradle`, the best way is  to use [bom file](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#using-the-bom)

Comment: You didn't add view model related dependencies. See this page: https://semicolonspace.com/gradle-files-jetpack-compose/ These are the gradle files used in the project (music button)

Answer (score 3):

What really worked for me is that first in the build.gradle file app level I have added the following dependancy

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1"
```

I have also made sure the androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx is version 2.4.1 which wasn't the case

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
```

Here is a repo incase of further inspection https://github.com/waithakaFM/Restaurants

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file extensions for all files correct (e.g. build.gradle does not have .kt etc)

Answer (score -1):

Import the above dependency to solve your problem
"implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")"

Comment: Code need formatting